# Retrieve Values manually from XML InnerXML

Tags: c#, xml

I have been trying to deserialize the InnerXML into a class and for some reason the XML keeps changing shape and however many times I try to get the class right it seems to change shape again.

So I have given up and decided to try another method.

Is it possible to retrieve the value of a parameter within the InnerXML manually using c#?

Say for example, my XML innerXML looked like this:

```
<Timestamp>2014-08-22T21:45:00Z</Timestamp>
<Subscriber>https://www.dogdoza.co.uk</Subscriber>
<Order>
  <OrderID>111867</OrderID>
  <InvoiceNumber>DOZA-9725410</InvoiceNumber>
  <CustomerID>4542</CustomerID>
```

Is it possible to pull out say the value of Subscriber

If this is possible I can just pull out the values I want manually. Not ideal, but there are only about 10...

I have looked around but not managed to find any code I can get working..

Can anyone please give me any guidance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do achieve what you want using [`LINQ to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
XElement myXml = XElement.Load(@"XmlLocationHere");
XElement subscriber = myXml.Descendants("Subscriber").FirstOrDefault();
```

[`XElement.Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a collection of the descendant elements for this document or element, in document order. This method will return an `IEnumerable<XElement>`, since there might be more than one "Subscriber" element, but in your case, we choose [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx), which returns the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Try [loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your XML into an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then try to use [XPathSelectElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the specific value you want.

It could be that you need to wrap your inner xml into a root element, because it doesn't accept multiple roots.

Pseudo example:

```
// set up your xml document
string xml = "<rootelement>" + myInnerXml + "</rootelement>";
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
doc.Parse(xml);

XElement subscriber = doc.XPathSelectElement("/rootelement/Subscriber");
string value = subscriber.Value;
```